# lockForUpdate in union with laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Here is my code

```php
DB::beginTransaction();
$user = $request->user();

$ticket_types = OnlineTicketingTicketType::where('online_ticketing_event_id', $request->event_id)
    ->where('status', 1)
    ->whereIn('id', $request->ticket_types_array)
    ->lockForUpdate()
    ->get();

$ticket_entries = OnlineTicketingTicketEntry::where('online_ticketing_event_id', $request->event_id)
    ->where("online_ticketing_ticket_type_id", $ticket_types[0]->id)
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where("status", "available")
            ->orWhere(function ($query) {
                $query->where("status", "lock for payment")
                    ->Where('expired_date', '<', now());
            });
    })
    ->take($request->ticket_types[$ticket_types[0]->id]);

for($i = 1; $i < count($request->ticket_types_array); $i++) {
    $ticket_entries = $ticket_entries->union(
        OnlineTicketingTicketEntry::where('online_ticketing_event_id', $request->event_id)
            ->where("online_ticketing_ticket_type_id", $ticket_types[$i]->id)
            ->where(function ($query) {
                $query->where("status", "available")
                    ->orWhere(function ($query) {
                        $query->where("status", "lock for payment")
                            ->Where('expired_date', '<', now());
                    });
            })
            ->take($request->ticket_types[$ticket_types[$i]->id])
    );
}

$tickets = $ticket_entries->lockForUpdate()->get();

OnlineTicketingTicketEntry::whereIn('id', $tickets->pluck('id')->toArray())
    ->update([
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'status' => "lock for payment",
        'expired_date' => now()->addMinutes(10),
    ]);

DB::commit();
```

I already use `DB::transaction` in some where.

My problem is I cannot lock the row in the `$ticket_entries`. I try to add some `sleep()` in the code and Log the info. I see that since I lock `$ticket_types` in the begin so when user getting same ticket_type, they need to do it one by one. The Log with timestamp also show that it is work. Users finish the api one by one.

However, after first user commit and the ticket should be update with the user_id. Second user can also get the same record and user_id is null.

In my code, i think that it will work by user A lock ticket_type --->  select and lock all ticket_entry in different ticket_type  ---> update the entries  ---> commit it. Then user B will do the same things. lock same ticket_type --->  select and lock all ticket_entry which is same type but not same entry_id in different ticket_type ---> commit, but now all user get the same ticket_entries. I think that the problem is they already get the entries in some where before lock the row.

Comment: lockForUpdate() doesn't work with union() queries in Laravel.

Comment: thanks, sir, do you know where the place in the Laravel doc that tells us lockForUpdate() doesn't work with the union()?

Comment: Also, I try to add sleep(6) after $ticket_types->lockforUpdate, so user B should wait 6 sec to get $ticket_entries after he gets records of $ticket_types. So user B should not get the same $ticket_entries as user A. But user B gets the same $ticket_entries as user A.

Comment: Looks like a race condition issue. you can use the with method to load the related OnlineTicketingTicketType models along with the ticket_entries in a single query. This way the entries will be locked within the same transaction.